# IBM Watson Assistant get intent name from confidence array

Tags: watson-assistant

I have question, hav can I get name of intent from array like this?

```
[
{
    "intent": "intent_1",
    "confidence": 0.6298341751098633
},
{
    "intent": "intent_2",
    "confidence": 0.6175673961639405
},
{
    "intent": "intent_3",
    "confidence": 0.23323171436786652
},
{
    "intent": "intent_4",
    "confidence": 0.22574123442173005
}
```

]

I want to save in variable name "intent_2".

Comment: Do you want to get a name like "intent_2"?

Comment: I solved the problem. At first, I filter the table by name, and then get the name.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that array is stored in `context` in `my_array`, you can get name of the first intent with expression like this: `<? $my_array[0].intent ?>`.